# How do I define SQLAlchemy FKs and relationships to allow the database to cascade delete?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How does one define a ForeignKey and relationship such that one can disable SQLAlchemy's FK-nullifying behavior?
The documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#passive-deletes) seems to describe the use of 
`passive_deletes=True` to allow the database to cascade delete, but only in the context of defining the `cascade` relationship 
property [documented here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html?highlight=cascade), a property which it seems 
to me defines how SQLAlchemy will perform the cascade deletion itself, *which is explicitly described as slower than the database engine's 
cascade deletion* [in this section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html?highlight=cascade#delete) 
(see the green box titled *ORM-level “delete” cascade vs. FOREIGN KEY level “ON DELETE” cascade*).

To use the database's cascade delete, are we supposed to do the following?

1. define `ondelete="CASCADE"` on the `ForeignKey` column,
2. define `passive_deletes=True` on the same relationships,
3. ***AND*** define a `cascade="delete, delete-orphan"` parameter on all relationships between the objects?

It is step 3 that I seem to be confused about: it seems to be defining the cascade for SQLAlchemy rather than allowing the database 
to perform it's own deletion. But SQLAlchemy seems to want to null out all dependent foreign keys *before* the database can get a 
chance to cascade delete. I need to disable this behavior, but `passive_deletes=True` seems not to do it on its own.

The (late) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38770040/9691276) explicitly addresses my issue, but it is not working. He states

> There's an important caveat here. Notice how I have a relationship specified with `passive_deletes=True`? If you don't have that, the entire thing will not work. 
>   This is because by default when you delete a parent record SqlAlchemy does something really weird. 
>   It sets the foreign keys of all child rows to `NULL`. So if you delete a row from `parent_table` where `id = 5`, then it will basically execute
>   `UPDATE child_table SET parent_id = NULL WHERE parent_id = 5`

In my code

```
class Annotation(SearchableMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    locked = db.Column(db.Boolean, index=True, default=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)

    HEAD = db.relationship("Edit",
            primaryjoin="and_(Edit.current==True,"
            "Edit.annotation_id==Annotation.id)", uselist=False,
            lazy="joined", passive_deletes=True)

    edits = db.relationship("Edit",
            primaryjoin="and_(Edit.annotation_id==Annotation.id,"
                "Edit.approved==True)", lazy="joined", passive_deletes=True)
    history = db.relationship("Edit",
            primaryjoin="and_(Edit.annotation_id==Annotation.id,"
                "Edit.approved==True)", lazy="dynamic", passive_deletes=True)
    all_edits = db.relationship("Edit",
            primaryjoin="Edit.annotation_id==Annotation.id", lazy="dynamic",
            passive_deletes=True)

class Edit(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    edit_num = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    approved = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    rejected = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    annotation_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
            db.ForeignKey("annotation.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True)
    hash_id = db.Column(db.String(40), index=True)
    current = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True, passive_deletes=True)

    annotation = db.relationship("Annotation", foreign_keys=[annotation_id])
    previous = db.relationship("Edit",
            primaryjoin="and_(remote(Edit.annotation_id)==foreign(Edit.annotation_id),"
            "remote(Edit.edit_num)==foreign(Edit.edit_num-1))")
    priors = db.relationship("Edit",
            primaryjoin="and_(remote(Edit.annotation_id)==foreign(Edit.annotation_id),"
            "remote(Edit.edit_num)<=foreign(Edit.edit_num-1))",
            uselist=True, passive_deletes=True)
```

simply setting `passive_deletes=True` on the parent relationship *is not working*. I also thought perhaps it was being caused by the relationship
from the child to it's siblings (the relationships `Edit.previous` and `Edit.priors`) but setting `passive_deletes=True` on those two relationships
does *not* solve the problem, and it causes the following warnings when I simply run an `Edit.query.get(n)`:

> /home/malan/projects/icc/icc/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:1790: SAWarning: On Edit.previous, 'passive_deletes' is normally configured on one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-many relationships only.
>     % self)
>
> /home/malan/projects/icc/icc/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:1790: SAWarning: On Edit.priors, 'passive_deletes' is normally configured on one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-many relationships only.
>     % self)

I have actually found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439058/not-working-example-with-passive-deletes-directive-in-sqlalchemy-doc) interesting question from 2015 that has never had an answer. It details a failed attempt to execute documentation code.

Comment: `passive_deletes` seems to be the correct option. Having multiple relationships isn't bad form, and are often necessary to model the situation at hand (and seems like a good fit for your need). Initial guess is that all the relationships might need them, since it might otherwise force setting the reference to NULL before the database gets the chance to cascade

Comment: @MatsLindh Unfortunately, it didn't seem to help!

Comment: Please include your relationship configurations, as they are pertinent to the issue at hand.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that after a thorough attempt to analyze my relationships, I have discovered the problem.

First, I will note, `passive_deletes=True` is the *only* necessary parameter. You do *not* need to define `cascade` at all to take advantage of the database's cascade system.

More importantly, my problem seems to have stemmed from my tree of foreign-key depedencies. I had a cascade that looked like this:

```
       Annotation
      /     |    \ 
   Vote    Edit   annotation_followers
           /  \ 
    EditVote   tags
```

Where `ondelete="CASCADE"` was defined for each `parent_id` column on each child class. Until I set passive_deletes on *all* of the children in the graph, the nullification behavior continued to misbehave.

For anyone running into a similar problem, my advice is: thoroughly analyze *all* of your intersecting relationships, and define `passive_deletes=True` on all of them that it makes sense.

That said, there are still complications I'm working out; for instance, on a many-to-many table the id's aren't even nullifying. Possible next question.